# Rearrange list view items in SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a database SQLite and then using SimpleCursorAdapter , I display values into list view. However, I want to re arrange the list view items and display the ones starting with ID #1 in top and then ID number 2, so on.. the issue is, I am not able to grasp concept of re allocating list view items based on some ID number from Content provider. 
If you know , please share. Thank you.

Comment: Without any code it's difficult to comment but basically you need to provide some kind of 'sort order' when you query the provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQLite correctly you should be able to do a "order by id" when you query up the DB.

If thats not the case then what I would do is build out your data into a collection.

Have your generic object implement the comparable interface.

like so http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-use-comparable-interface.html

When you call Collections.sort(contentfromtheprovider); It will sort based on the ID like you wish to do.

Answer (score 2):

just format  your query, here's the page that helped me.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565%28v=sql.90%29.aspx